# BlobCache.UserAccount cloud syncronize on Android

Tags: android, ios, uwp, xamarin.forms, akavache

I am trying to understand BlobCache.UserAccount option using akavache. So far I could successfully implemented BlobCache.LocalMachine which works only offline. 
Accoridng to akavache documentation;

**Xamarin.iOS** will may remove data, stored in BlobCache.LocalMachine, to free up disk space (only if your app is not running). The locations BlobCache.UserAccount and BlobCache.Secure will be backed up to iCloud and iTunes.

**Windows 10 (UWP)** will replicate BlobCache.UserAccount and BlobCache.Secure to the cloud and synchronize it to all user devices on which the app is installed

I guess this is something done automatically by the OS when you place the data into the certain folders, it is being backed up and this is what akavache is doing. Is that correct?

If yes, Is there a way to have something similar with Android. Nothing is described for Android. Is there some backup happening on google drive or we can implement easily?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is iOS specific indeed. I tried to look it up into the code, but couldn't find something specific for the UserAccount. So, I think your assumption is correct. It might be for a different reason though, but I honestly think its iOS specific.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like with android it doesn't store into google drive

https://github.com/akavache/Akavache/blob/master/src/Akavache/Android/AndroidFilesystemProvider.cs#L40

I haven't done that much with saving files into google drive but it doesn't seem quite as straight forward as it is on Windows or iOS. On Windows just save into a Roaming Folder and run with it. Where as with Android it seems less plug and play

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started

> Creating a new Android application that uses the Google Drive
>   Android API requires several steps.

I think in theory you could register your own IFileSystemHandler into Splat if you want to wire that connection up.